# Mixin Express Route dependency checker

Tags: express, dependencies, pug, mixins, abstraction

We have some pug mixins to make recurring modules for our website, one of those is making a contact form. To handle the responses for this we have a post method.
The relevant/simplified code:

**routes/index.js**

```
const routes = require('express').Router();
routes.get('contact-us', (req, res) => res.render('contactus', {}))
routes.post('contact-us', processForm)
module.exports = routes
```

**views/mixins.pug**

```
mixin contactusform
  form(method='post')
    input(type='text' placeholder='content not that relevant' name='whatever')
    button(type='submit')
```

**views/contactus.pug**

```
extends ../layout/page
include mixins
block content
  +contactusform
```

If the `+contactusform` is now rendered but the `POST` route is not defined, the server will start without errors and someone would get a 404. I am not sure what the best solution is.
Writing tests for this seems convoluted. Certainly because in theory this could be statically checked [afaik](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=afaik).

It also feels like this is a seperation of concern thing and I should solve this differently altogether. Is there some standard for how you layout these types of things or is 'testing' the best I can get. Any input would be very welcome.